# Can you use "say" to refer to things on the internet?

Tags: meaning, word-usage

When referring to something you read on the internet, can you use "say?" For example, can you say, "he said it on a forum" when speaking about a message someone posted. Or does say only refer to spoken words?

Comment: It says in the bible you can

Comment: Not only "say", but you can use "hear" as well.

Comment: We always knew that a book or a newspaper *says* things, so a web page is no different.

Answer (score 6):

This is commonly done. However, "Say" could possibly cause confusion,  which you have noted. There could be some confusion over whether the user actually said that, or just posted it.

I think the best way to avoid this, would be to use "wrote it". For example:

> He wrote that the word 'use' is often used wrongly.

not

> He said that the word 'use' is often used wrongly. (Did he actually say it? Or did he post it?)

Of course, usually this can be determined by the context (e.g. Language hacker posted on a forum last week. He said that...).

But to be on the safe side, "wrote" would be better.

Answer (score 3):

Two of the meanings reported by the NOAD for *say* are:

> - (of a text or a symbolic representation) convey specified information or instructions
> - enable a listener or reader to learn or understand something by conveying or revealing (information or ideas)

In the second case, "I don't want to say too much" can used for who is listening or who is reading. *Say* can also be used figuratively as in, "the movie's title says it all."

Comment: This "extended reach" for the verb *say* also applies to *see*. I have a blind friend who quite unselfconciously says things like "I'll see you later". Come to that, I think he also says "I read that" when he means he read an audio book. It's so natural one tends not to notice - even he might not even be able to definitively say one way or the other whether he uses "read" in that way.

Answer (score -1):

"Say" can indeed be used to refer to expressing ideas in written form. Compare "What does his letter say?" and "The sign says 'STOP'".